# Change join table by another entity in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, database-design, cascade, join

I have 2 entities: Person and Phone (one-to-many relationship). I want to use JoinTable:

```
class Person

    @OneToMany()
    @JoinTable(name="PERSON_PHONES", 
            joinColumns={ @JoinColumn(name="PERSON_ID") },
            inverseJoinColumns={ @JoinColumn(name="PHONE_ID") })
public List<Phone> getPhones(){...}
```

But, for some reason I can't use JoinTable, so I need to write class PersonPhone. I doubt about relations, may it be like this?

Person -> PersonPhone: one-to-many bidirectional
PersonPhone -> Phone: one-to-one unidirectional

And another question, if I define this cascade rules:

```
class Person {

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="person")
public List<PersonPhone> getPersonPhones() {...}
...
}

class PersonPhone {

@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
public Phone getPhone(){...}
...
}

// class phone has not fields for this relation
```

will phones for a person delete when person deleted?

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear why you can't use a join table, but if you keep this design, then yes, thanks to the `cascade=CascadeType.ALL` that you defined on both associations, deleting a person will delete its `PersonPhone`s, which will then cascade to `Phone`.

The `PersonPhone` entity is only useful if it has more than the person and the phone attributes.

Comment: PersonPhone hasn't other attributes, but there is JuredicalPerson entity, that has it's own join table with phones,that's why I want to use PersonPhone. And I can't use JoinTable because of constraints of program architecture that may be time consuming to rewrite. But I also don't want to create bad database design because of this constraints... Watch for best solutioon :)

Comment: I don't see why the fact the another join table exists prevent you from using a join table for this association.

Comment: I get this idea here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991830/what-table-structure-to-use-hibernate

Comment: Whatever the inheritance strategy you choose, the association should be defined only once, in the base Person entity. This association, and the join table going with the association, is inherited by the other entities. Read the chapter about inheritance in the hibernate reference manual.